# Abandoned Cart Emails (Expresso-Store)

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, postmaster

The website I am busy developing contains a shopping cart and after 2 hours of no user activity, the current cart is considered abandoned and should send the user an email regarding this.

I am using Expresso-Store as my shopping cart and considering the Postmaster add-on for handling my emails. Will the Postmaster add-on handle the sending of email after 2 hours of inactivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think postmaster supports this out of the box.

However, it should be fairly trivial to add support for. Store keeps all incomplete carts in the exp_store_orders table (with `completed_date` set to `NULL`), so it would be fairly easy to grab the most recent abandoned carts and send a follow up email to them.

Comment: To add to this, you could try writing a plug-in to query the exp_store_orders table as Adrian suggests and then have that placed in a template which is called on a fairly regular basis by a CRON job. :)